# Capture string to a character but not including the character

Tags: regex

With the string `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?hello=world`, you can use `/^.+\?/` to capture `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?`. How can I just capture `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`.

Comment: What language are you using?  If you're in PHP, you can use the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) built-in function to parse the parts of your URL.  Better to use existing, working, tested code than to roll your own.

Comment: It's not really a URL-specific question, this example is very useful to understand with a URL. I really wanted to know how to capture to a character but not the character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `^[^?]+`

This will capture until a question mark is found, but the question mark will not be in the result.

[Check it out](http://regexr.com?33162).

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the portion of regex that matches the required string in parenthesis and use groups to retrieve that.

```
 /(^.+)\?/
```

Group 1 will contain the entire matched string except the trailing `?`.

Answer (score 1):

use this regexrpession `/^.+(?=\?)/`